# Pinch Zoom in Android

Tags: android, textview, zooming, pinch

I have a layout, which include some TextViews and ImageViews.
Haven't they created an easy way to include pinch zoom on an simple ScrollView/LinearLayout?
I have watched some codes, but they work only on ImageViews.

Recently I found [setDisplayZoomControls(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDisplayZoomControls(boolean)).

Is it possible to make this work on a layout with TextViews?
If no, maybe somebody provides a code, which will zoom in/out my layout with pinch zoom.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using android-pinch, it is supposed to work on web-views as well http://code.google.com/p/android-pinch/

Answer (score 1):

Also,

Take a look at this:
http://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/

It will enable you to add multi touch handlers to almost any widget.

Note that due to some hardware problems on older devices, you might not always get the right result.