# Android : to add zoom in text view

Tags: android, textview

i have defined a text view in my xml layout. But as sometimes it contains a lot of text so i want to add zoom so that when the user taps, it zooms my text. Can anyone please tell me how to do that?

Comment: you can use webview for hat right ?

Comment: what additional features does webview provide over textview?

Comment: don't use webview for this, a webview primary objective is to show html content.

Comment: did you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923470/pinching-zoom-for-text-view?

Comment: webview provide default zoom controls .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zoom might not be the right word for your problem, you actually want to **increase** textsize and maybe add some animation to it so it looks like a zooming effect.

- make a customView extending from TextView
- implement touch/onclick on this customView
- onCallback of these events increase fontsize

EXTRA: you could add animations to animate "the zoom"

Comment: but i want to increse the tex-size on touch like it appears to be zoom

Comment: yes you can do that, i will change the word decrease to increase, same story